# Show that the convex hull of a set S is the intersection of all convex sets that contain S

Tags: convex-analysis

Show that the convex hull of a set $S$ is the intersection of all convex sets that contain $S$. 
Suppose $H$ is the convex hull of $S$, and $D$ is the intersection of all convex sets contain $S$. Certainly, it's easy to prove that $H \subset D$, but how to prove that $D \subset H$?

Comment: What definition of convex hull are you using?

Comment: The definition : the set of all convex combinations of points in $C$

Comment: Do you know that the convex hull is itself a convex set? (This is a simple verification). If you kn ow this it is obvious that $D \subset H$.

Comment: I get it!Thanks!!